# Is it possible to enable BitCode for an iOS app that uses Qt?

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, bitcode

I have an iOS app that was made using Qt 5.6 and distributed via Xcode 7.2 on the AppStore.

When I try to enable BitCode I get the following error during the link phase :

```
ld: -u and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
```

I suspect that Qt was not built with BitCode enabled and that's why the linker is complaining. Am  I correct or am I doing something wrong ? If it's Qt related, is it possible to build a Qt version for iOS with BitCode enabled ?

Qt 5.6 was installed using the online installer. It was not compiled on this machine.

Comment: Discussion on this topic on https://forum.qt.io/topic/65256/bitcode-for-ios. Still no answer.